# share internet from one location to another location

Tags: networking

i have search so much for this but i cannot get the idea the exact process of doing it. say i have internet connection from a **certain place** then i want to use that connection to another place which approximately `4 kilometers` away.

Is this possible that i can share it?
is there a way that i can connect to that certain place where internet access is available?

Comment: You also need to ensure that your service provider's terms allow you to share the service at all. Else you can find your service terminated at **certain place** for violation of your contract.

Comment: im thinking , something like a proxy

Comment: Have you thought about setting up a VPN connection ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like yes but i dont know if that really works.. and i dont have definite guide on setting it up

Comment: You should be able to find a lot of resource online on how to do that and if you get stuck SU is always there. [my google search](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/)

Comment: maybe i should try setting up a vpn then try connecting it from other place :)

Comment: Is there any kind of network infrastructure between the 2 places you are trying to connect? You'd need to connect them first, then worry about sharing the internet connection later. A VPN or Proxy would be no use whatsoever, if you don't have any kind of network between the 2 locations to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a mean of connecting the 2 places, and it will likely to be expensive. 
While laying cables between them would probably be out of the question, you could set up a Point to Point Wireless Bridge.

Have a look here: https://www.ubnt.com/broadband/

And here: https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Stories/My-first-Long-Range-WiFi-Setup-with-internet-access-point-at-one/cns-p/866594

Good luck

Comment: oh. :( that is really be expensive :(